# window.onload only execute once, it doesn't work after form submission

Tags: javascript, html, onload

I have a child window which is opened by a parent window. I need to do something every time the child window reloads( the first time it opens, every time the form submit ).

But I find window.onload will only execute once, it's not triggered when the form is submit, and the page refreshes.

How can I detect the page refresh and do something accordingly?

Comment: > "But I find window.onload will only execute once". What did you base this assumption on? I'm sure the child window's onload event fires every time a document is loaded. The reference to the parent window (`opener`) would be lost though when the document in the child window is reloaded (by, for e.g., a form submit). `window.opener` is only available when a browser window is opened from JavaScript using `window.open()` function.

Comment: Why not ajax the form then react on `success` or `error`

Comment: @marekful, I'm sure onload event just fires once, I just did the test.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, because the child page is legacy code and belongs to another team. I can't do too much change, otherwise it's going to cause problem.